# Delete record if it doesnt exists in other db anymore

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm getting data from database A and passing it to database B via hibernate, what I want  to do is when record for the table **CERTIFICATE** doesn't exist in **dbA** anymore, to be deleted in **dbB**, when I'm updating.

For example in **dbB** I have certificate `"A"` and `"B"` for `employeeId=1`, when updating  again the certifcate `"A"` is deleted in **dbA** and a new one `"C"` is added, so in **dbB** should be certificate `"B" and "C"` only, after save-update.

Right now what I'm doing before updating the EMPLOYEE and CERTIFICATE tables, is deleting all certificates for the employeeId = x

```
String hqlDeleteCertificates = "delete Certificates where employeeId= :employeeId";
Query query = session.createQuery(hqlDeleteCertificates );
query.setInteger("employeeId", employeeId);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Is there a better way to do it in one transaction while save-update, changing something in the mapping configuration

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   first_name VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   last_name  VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   salary     INT  default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table CERTIFICATE (
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   certificate_name VARCHAR(30) default NULL,
   employee_id INT default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Hibernate mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">employee_seq</param>
        </generator>
      </id>
      <set name="certificates" lazy="false" cascade="all">
         <key column="employee_id" not-null="true"/>
         <one-to-many class="Certificate"/>
      </set>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary"/>
   </class>

   <class name="Certificate" table="CERTIFICATE">
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <param name="sequence">certificate_seq</param>
      </id>
      <property name="employee_id" column="employee_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
      <property name="name" column="certificate_name"/>
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `org.hibernate.classic.Lifecycle` interface and its methods. Implement this interface by one of your POJO's.

From the documentation:

**onSave:** called just before the object is saved
**onUpdate:** called just before an object is updated, ie. when Session.update() is called
**onDelete:** called just before an object is deleted
**onLoad:** called just after an object is loaded

There you can hook your code in `onUpdate` and do not care about it anymore.